# Regex - replacing pattern with equal number of '#' becoming very slow

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex for some email signatures (need to replace with same number of characters):

`re.sub('(Regards|Thanks|Thank you|Best|Sincerely|Cheers),?[\n\s]([A-Za-z]+[\s\S]*)',repl, body)`,

where `repl` is

```
def repl(m):
    return '#' * len(m.group())
```

This ends up taking a lot of time. I have a bunch of other similar regexes that are much faster. Is it because of all the or conditions? For example, if I just do `re.sub('(Regards),?[\n\s]([A-Za-z]+[\s\S]*)',repl, body)` it is much faster, but still not great. I have also tried compiling it as I am using this on many emails but that didn't really help at all. Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Effectively, what is the total length of input that is parsed by this regex?

Comment: You're being a victim of ReDoS for yourself: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS

Comment: Yes, you may make it faster, `r'\b(Regards|Thank(?:s| you)|Best|Sincerely|Cheers),?[\n\s]([A-Za-z]+[\s\S]*)'`

Comment: This `[\n\s]` is overlapping terms, replace it with `\s`

Comment: There is nothing in the regex that constitutes catastrophic bactracking. The real problem is that the replacement generated is equal to the length of the match. So `[\s\S]*` always matches to the _end of the string_ however big that is.

Comment: Well, right, there is no point keeping `\n` there. Generic advice: if you have to deal with long texts, and your patterns are not just `\d+`-like (not so simple), use PyPi regex module, do not use `re` then. Use `r'\b(Regards|Thank(?:s| you)|Best|Sincerely|Cheers),?\s+([A-Za-z]+[\s\S]*)'`, and if it is still slow with `re`, intall and use `regex`.

Comment: Try removing that `[\s\S]*` term.

Comment: @Maxt8r thank you, that seemed to be it. much better. The reason I had that term in there was because I did not necessarily want to go the the end of the string in case it was a reply to an email where there would be stuff beneath the signature. It was actually supposed to be `[\s\S]*(?:From)?', but I think because there are not too many cases of that it slows it down.

Comment: `[\s\S]*` at the end of a pattern does not slow down matching, unless you have other patterns following it. It is greedy and matches any character.

Comment: Yeah, its that whole `return '#' * len(m.group())` thing. And being generated on the stack. Depends on how _big_ the file is. Like 1 GB is a big one.